# How Spine add and removing class active. Any idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spine.js

I want to know in `spine` how to add and remove `active class` for div. In the firebug I saw initially 4 div inside, the first div having class as active when i click new link the div class active was removed for the first div at the same time the second div getting the class active. I don't have any idea how `Spine add and removing class active`.

By jquery we can do this. But i want to do this in spine (`spine_rails`)

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Manager](http://spinejs.com/docs/manager) and [Stack](http://spinejs.com/docs/stacks) classes, I'm pretty sure that's what you're looking for. Stack has an internal Manager, which deals with keeping active state on only one controller at a time. It does that simply by adding the css class "active" to the currently active controller. From the docs:

> A Stack doesn't alter the display CSS property of its controllers, but rather simply adds and removes an active class.

That explains what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for due to lack of information.

However, you can check spine stacks to see whether that's what you want.

http://spinejs.com/docs/stacks

Answer (score 0):

To remove active class in spine_rails add following line  to your spine:controller `@el.removeClass('active')`